# Loop through a JSON object array and takeout objects based on condition

Tags: angularjs, json, loops

I am trying to figure out a way to loop through a JSON object and pickout the objects which meets a particular condition. I need to create a new JSON with the result.
I have a tree component with check boxes in nodes. I want to extract only the nodes which are checked. The checked nodes can be identified by `"isSelected": true`

My JSON is - https://pastebin.com/RHR2tAxZ

I am new to Angular and have not handled a JSON loop before. Can anyone help me to sort this out?

Comment: "isSelected": true is there inside node as well as node1 of your json, based on which "isSelected": true  do you want to check?

Comment: @vivz i need the inner nodes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **`isSelected` property on the checkbox,

```
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="listitem.isSelected" >
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.newList =[];
 $scope.list=
    [
  {
    "node": [
      {
        "node": [],
        "pageName": "Upload Files",
        "isSelected": false,
        "node1": [],
        "pagedefinitionId": 7
      },
      {
        "node": [],
        "pageName": "Download Files",
        "isSelected": false,
        "node1": [],
        "pagedefinitionId": 8
      }
    ],
    "pageName": "Manage Files",
    "isSelected": false,
    "node1": [],
    "pagedefinitionId": 4
  },
  {
    "node": [],
    "pageName": "Vendor Request",
    "isSelected": false,
    "node1": [
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "pageControlId": 89,
        "elementIdentifier": "vendorRequest.add",
        "pageDefinitionId": 355
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "pageControlId": 90,
        "elementIdentifier": "vendorRequest.submitForApproval",
        "pageDefinitionId": 355
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "pageControlId": 91,
        "elementIdentifier": "vendorRequest.complete",
        "pageDefinitionId": 355
      }
    ],
    "pagedefinitionId": 355
  }
];
$scope.getselected = function(){
  angular.forEach( $scope.list,function(key,value){
  console.log(key);
      if(key.isSelected){
        $scope.newList.push(key);
      }
  });
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat ="listitem in list">
  <label>
     {{ listitem.pageName }}
   </label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="listitem.isSelected" > 
 </div>
  <button ng-click="getselected()">getSelected</button>
   <h1>selected ones{{newList}}</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay, so will I get the entire list of nodes which are selected in a separate JSON if I use that property?

Comment: Yeah you can do that

Comment: I dont want to display the items, but need them in a JSON array

Comment: This loop is going though only the main branches. I need to get the objects in leaf nodes as well.

Comment: Follow the same logic

Comment: Its lot of foreach loops in my case. I was looking for something sort of a recursive function.